# Intercept Javascript HTMLImageElement constructor

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, intercept

I try to intercept Image() constructor of HTMLImageElement:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

```
var origImgConstr = HTMLImageElement.prototype.constructor;                                                   
Image = function(width, height) {                                                                             
  console.log('image constructor!');                                                                          
  return new origImgConstr(arguments);                                                                        
};
```

but I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor(…)
```

The same result if I replace `Image` with `HTMLImageElement`.

What do I miss?

Comment: It's specifically `Image` you want to intercept?

Comment: Yes. Is it anyhow special?

Comment: `HTMLImageElement` is an interface, not a class.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? There are other ways that images can be created too.

Comment: ...well anyway, if you needed to capture all images being created, this won't do it. If you only needed calls to `Image` that you make, I wouldn't bother messing with the original constructor, but would simply create a different function that calls `new Image`.

Comment: @squint: How would you propose to intercept creation of all images on the page?

Comment: @rlib: As far as I'm aware, it's impossible cross-browser. What you *can* do is catch all images as they're added to the document via a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). But that's only catching them at the point of being added, not created.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Is there special solution for Chrome? Or Firefox?

Comment: @rlib: I'm sorry to say I don't remember. I remember I looked into this several months ago, but my aged and feeble mind only stored and indexed the "I can't do it reliably cross-browser" part. :-)

Comment: @rlib: You'd need to override `.outerHTML`, `.innerHTML`, `.insertAdjacentHTML()`, `.cloneNode()`, `.createElement()` and `Image()` for starters. That still wouldn't handle elements created when the page loads, so you'd need to do a DOM selection early to get those.

Comment: There is a "live" collection of images at `document.images` if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image` and `HTMLImageElement`'s constructor aren't the same function. You can't override the latter reliably cross-browser.

**Preface:** Overriding `Image` will not intercept creation of `img` elements by the HTML parser or `document.createElement` calls. As far as I'm aware, that's impossible cross-browser. What you *can* do is catch all images as they're added to the document via a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). But that's only catching them at the point of being added, not created.

**But:** You've said it's `Image`, specifically, you want to override, so take the original value of `Image` before replacing it, and use that.

Example:

```js
var originalImage = Image;
Image = function(width, height) {
  var result;
  console.log("Intercepted");
  switch (arguments.length) {
      case 0:
        result = new originalImage();
        break;
      case 1:
        result = new originalImage(width);
        break;
      default:
        result = new originalImage(width, height);
        break;
  }
  return result;
};

var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQIK0.jpg?s=64&g=1";
document.body.appendChild(img);
img = new Image(32, 20);
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQIK0.jpg?s=64&g=1";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

In ES2015, in case that's an option for you:

```js
const originalImage = Image;
Image = function(...args) {
  console.log("Intercepted");
  return new originalImage(...args);
};

let img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQIK0.jpg?s=64&g=1";
document.body.appendChild(img);
img = new Image(32, 20);
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQIK0.jpg?s=64&g=1";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Does `new originalImage(width, height)` not work reliably? I'd figure they'd consider `undefined` to be a non-number.

Comment: @squint: That's me being defensive. :-) I don't *know* that the implementaton isn't going to look at the number of arguments actually received, so... (And thank heavens for ES2015's spread notation, in ES2015 it would be a nice clear `Image = function(...args) { console.log("Intercepted"); return new originalImage(...args); };` )

Comment: *"...thank heavens for ES2015's spread notation..."* For that and so many other additions that begin to make the native syntax actually pleasant to use.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "Overriding Image will not intercept creation elements by the HTML parser... As far as I'm aware, that's impossible cross-browser." If you remember how to do that in some specific / non-reliable way, please update your answer!